# Cannot install ruby version on redhat

Tags: ruby, linux, redmine, redhat

I have the following problem and whatever I try, nothing helps. I hope someone could help me with this.

I have a redhat server and I'm trying to install redmine on it. Redmine needs Ruby >= 1.8.7 to run so I installed it and when I execute ruby -v in the console it says I have version 1.8.7 (so that's great)

```
[root@vms redmine]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when i try to install the passenger gem I need to run redmine on Apache it says I don't have ruby 1.8.7

```
[root@vms redmine]# gem install passenger
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
rake requires Ruby version >= 1.8.6
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need newer ruby, you have `patchlevel 0`, try to get `patchlevel 173` at least.
[RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) can help you.

Comment: Yep either that, or use REE http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/download.html (from the makers of  passenger so they have a bundled passenger you can build, lean & swift).

Answer (score 0):

Using vendor build ruby packages is an exercise in frustration.

For anything with ruby it's easier just to use **RVM** and build a virtual environment. You can then build exactly what you need and have an environment you can replicate reliably. Also you won't end up clobbering your vendor's Ruby install.